# render :new is not working anymore when I'm using services

Tags: ruby, service, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

I'm trying to learn about services in Rails in order to avoid fat controllers.

Here a tried a simple product review creation

```
class ProductReviewsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_product, only: :create

  def new
    @product_review = ProductReview.new
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])   end

  def create
    if AddReviewService.call(product_review_params, @product)
      redirect_to product_path(@product)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def set_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])   end

  def product_review_params
    params.require(:product_review).permit(:content, :rating)   end end
```

The thing is that in the case of wrong parameters for the review the `render :new` generates the following error :

[screenshot of error received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gem2g.png)

```
Showing /home/miklw/code/michaelwautier/multitenant_app/app/views/product_reviews/new.html.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined method 'model_name' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #3):
1 <h1>New review for <%= @product.name %></h1>
2 
3 <%= simple_form_for [@product, @product_review] do |f| %>
4 <%= f.input :content %>
5 <%= f.input :rating %>
6 <%= f.button :submit %>

Rails.root: /home/miklw/code/michaelwautier/multitenant_app

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/product_reviews/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_product_reviews_new_html_erb__802305224391576972_70155240081100'
app/controllers/product_reviews_controller.rb:14:in `create'
Request
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Z7YeYvXKKr7uYhANlevZ4H8U00p9givKzXzfue4pNFk0jE2DtTNY7Eacqati+V8IihSofLc2WPa4ZBzR2o0v5w==",
 "product_review"=>{"content"=>"te", "rating"=>"9"},
 "commit"=>"Create Product review",
 "product_id"=>"4"}
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
Response
Headers:

None
```

In the error page console, if I type @product, I get the expected product object, but @product_review is nil.

BUT, if I use the regular way (see below), the form gets re-render as it should, with the notice message of the form

```
class ProductReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: :create

  def new
    @product_review = ProductReview.new
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  end

  def create
    @product_review = ProductReview.new(product_review_params)
    @product_review.product = @product
    if @product_review.save
      redirect_to product_path(@product)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def set_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  end

  def product_review_params
    params.require(:product_review).permit(:content, :rating)
  end
end
```

Any idea what could cause this issue ?

EDIT : Here is the service I call :

```
class AddReviewService < ApplicationService
  attr_reader :content, :rating

  def initialize(params, product)
    @content = params[:content]
    @rating = params[:rating]
    @product = product
  end

  def call
    review = ProductReview.new(content: @content, rating: @rating)
    review.product = @product
    return true if review.save
    return false
  end
end
```

EDIT 2 : returning the review when saved

```
  def call
    review = ProductReview.new(content: @content, rating: @rating)
    review.product = @product
    return review if review.save
    return false
  end
```

Comment: Why do you expect the first version of the controller to work? You never set the `@product_review` variable, the error says that something (as it turns out, `@product_review`) is `nil`. As soon as you set the variable, it works.

Comment: You never showed us the `AddReviewService` class, so I don't know what behaviour is encapsulated there, but regardless, it doesn't look like you're setting `@product_review` anywhere - and that's the problem.

Comment: the instance variables defined in controller vs service are different. Only the ones defined in the controller will be available in the view. If you need to pass data from the service to the view, you need to first get the value from the service to the controller, then assign an instance variable in the controller ..

Comment: I've added the `AddReviewService` in my post.
Indeed when I set the `@product_review` in the controller, I don't have an error anymore, I thought the instance variable was passed to the controller. But the error messages for the input are not rendered. How can I make it so the `@product_review` in the service is passed to the controller ? @max-pleaner @tom-lord

Comment: Have `def call` return the review if it was succesfully saved. Then in the controller, assign that return value to an instance variable. If it's unclear I can make an answer.

Comment: Shouldn't I return the review if it was not saved ? As the issue only appear on re-rendering when the params are not goog ?
If not, should it be like this then :
`see edit 2 in my post`

Comment: @maxpleaner I forgot to mention you in my last edit

Comment: I think that looks good.